# Is "largely....." a participle phrase

Tags: usage, phrases

The earnings of company grew by 5.4%, largely contributed by the strong performance of the manufacturing segment.

Is the above sentence grammatical ? "largely.......segment" is it a participle phrase modifying "earnings" ?

Comment: It would be okay with an article before the word *company*; however, I think *The company's earnings* is more idiomatic. The way I see it, I see the phrase as a participle phrase (aka "participial phrase" and sometimes "participle clause"), and it modifies 5.4% rather than *earnings* (though it's true that 5.4% is the growth of the earnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor adjustment to your original sentence:

"The earnings of the company grew by 5.4%, largely contributed by the strong performance of the manufacturing segment."

Adding that "the" makes it grammatical, but "largely contributed by" is very hard to interpret, so I don't like the sentence much. Below, I'll give some alternatives.

The clause "largely contributed by the strong performance of the manufacturing segment" doesn't modify "earnings". As it's written, I would say the clause modifies an implicit  noun, "the increase". I'd call it a participial clause modifying a suppressed subject. That is, it looks to me like it's short for something like:

"The earnings of the company grew by 5.4%, an increase largely contributed by the strong performance of the manufacturing segment."

You could also view this as an independent clause in the passive voice with both the subject and main verb deleted, but the end result is the same and that analysis is more complicated. Either way, that the sentence leaves "an increase" unstated is the main reason why I feel it's borderline ungrammatical. Doing this is permitted in English in many cases, but in this context it makes the sentence confusing. Here are some revisions I'd be more enthusiastic about. Both of them modify the verb "grew" directly, without needing an implicit deleted subject:

"The company's earnings grew by 5.4%, largely due to the strong performance of the manufacturing segment."

As Damkerng T. says, "The company's earnings" is more idiomatic.

Here, I'd call "largely due to the strong performance of the manufacturing segment" a prepositional phrase modified by an adverb "largely". You can see a similar structure with "mostly after the rain", where "mostly" is an adverb modifying the prepositional phrase [<sub>PP</sub> after [<sub>NP</sub> [<sub>det</sub> the] [<sub>N</sub> rain]]]]. This prepositional phrase "due to..." modifies "grew"; this is easier to see if we write:

"The company's earnings grew due to its strong manufacturing segment."

Here, it's obvious that the "due to..." clause modifies "grew".

Another one I like better:

"The company's earnings grew by 5.4%, largely owing to the strong performance of the manufacturing segment."

The phrase "owing to the..." is a participial clause that modifies "grew" directly, and is modified in turn by "largely". Here, again, there is no implicit subject to figure out, because the dependent clause modifies a word in the main clause.